# In Java, how can a server change its RMI client's thread id?

Tags: java, rmi

I have a remote object that serves a number of clients via Java RMI and thus I need the remote object to be able to identify its clients. I'm thinking of assigning unique ids to client by having the remote object calling `Thread.currentThread().setId()`. I'm assuming that the server will see each client as a separate thread.

Could you please show me how I can test this approach with only one machine, which will play both the server and client parts?

And if you think it will not work, how can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm assuming that the server will see each client as a separate
>   thread.

You can't assume that. The RMI specification states that there are no guarantees about the association if any between server threads and client threads.

What you are looking for is RemoteServer.getClientHost().